# Increment Number with Grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to generate one column in select that are incremental number, with grouping one and other columns. Here's the query (The incremental number is in *"Name"*, example: NFO_X01_CH_**00001**)

```
SELECT
    ( CASE WHEN description LIKE '%(%' OR Name LIKE '%(%' THEN 
        ('NFO' || '_' || zone || '_CH_' || ***incremental number***) ELSE 
        ('NFO' || '_' || zone || '_P_' || ***incremental number***) END 
    ) "Name", 
    ( CASE WHEN description LIKE '%(%' OR Name LIKE '%(%' THEN 
        'MANHOLE' ELSE 
        'POTEAU' END 
    ) "SiteTypeId", 
    Description 
FROM 
    OSN_BL_site_BPE
```

The conditions:

- Each Site/Zone, has separate incremental number (return loop to 0 again)
- Each SiteTypeId (Manhole/Poteau/etc), has separate incremental number (return loop to 0 again)
- One Site/Zone could have more than one SiteTypeId, so the incremental number is different
- Each incremental number, has five digits (start by *0000x* or *000xx*)

And the result I want:

[image: Result I expected]

Comment: I don't understand what data you have that leads to the required result. I don't understand either why some MANHOLE_L4T are numbered 00004 to 00006 and another 00009. How do you get that order? Anyway, you are probably looking for `ROW_NUMBER`, which is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROW_NUMBER.html#GUID-D5A157F8-0F53-45BD-BF8C-AE79B1DB8C41

Comment: And [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```sql
SELECT 'NFO' || '_' || zone
       || CASE is_manhole WHEN 1 THEN '_CH_' ELSE '_P_' END
       || TO_CHAR(
            MOD(
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY is_manhole, zone ORDER BY rownum
              ),
              100000
            ),
            'FM00000'
         ) AS name,
       CASE is_manhole
       WHEN 1 THEN 'MANHOLE'
       ELSE 'POTEAU'
       END AS "SiteTypeId", 
       Description 
FROM (
  SELECT description,
         name,
         zone,
         CASE
         WHEN description LIKE '%(%' OR Name LIKE '%(%'
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END AS is_manhole
  FROM   OSN_BL_site_BPE
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=860ae5d4b33c75fff321d9391e25cf16)*